# Have Domain Open HTML File?

Tags: html, hosting

I am currently making a website, and have a folder containing CSS3 and HTML5 code in it. When I click on the index.html file, it opens up a local file and I can see my design and text in it. However, I am not sure how to have my website "point" to the index.html file, so it shows the content that is in the file. (I bought the domain with GoDaddy).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the directory does not have any other default files like default.php,default,html,etc and also there should be only one index file. if there is any index.php it will overtake index.html. Please make your question more clear and tell use which hosting are you using.....

Comment: I do not seem to have any index.html files. I am using Heroku, and am pushing my git project to it.

Comment: I basically forked this repo, https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample, added the necessary files, and replaced index.html.

Comment: any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Then i can say it's a problem with your hosting not DNS.

Answer (score 0):

**Check documentation** of the company that provides you **hosting** - the server has a list of files it looks for on disk in a given order. Only thing you need to do is to rename you file to match server's "lookup table".

Relevant part of configuration of the most popular web servers:

- apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html
- nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html